# Calling external elasticsearch server with secret key

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to call an external elasticsearch server hosted by [FacetFlow](http://facetflow.com). To connect to this I've been given a url with a secret key, and I've set this up in my application.yml

```
data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes: mysupersecretkey:@name.west-eu.azr.facetflow.io:443
```

When I try to run the application I get 
Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@name.west-eu.azr.facetflow.io:443"

It seems spring-boot sees everything before @ as hostname, and everything after @ as the port number.

Is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: Can you give more details on the factory method 'elasticseachClient' where this error happens? Also is cluster-nodes mapped to String or URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way the Spring Data Elasticsearch class [TransportClientFactoryBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/TransportClientFactoryBean.java) parses the server URL.  The code in there does not take care of the case where the URL is structured as `protocol://user:password@server:port/uri`.  Therefore, it ends up resolving `https` as the host name (which is the protocol) and the API key as the port number (which is the user).

You can file an issue with the [Spring Data Elasticsearch project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) to support Facetflow URLs.